# How do you compare characters?

Tags: java, random, char, compare

I just want to ask how to compare characters using letters in GUI.
Here is how I random a letter:

```
Random r = new Random();

char c = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
```

Then, when I want to compare it to an input letter, this is how I do:

```
char c;
if(x==c) {
    prompt.setText("Correct!");
    prompt.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
}
else if(x > c) {
    prompt.setText("Oops! Letter is lower");                
    prompt.setForeground(Color.RED);                      
}                  
else if(x < c) {                      
    prompt.setText("Oops! Letter is higher");                     
    prompt.setForeground(Color.RED);                  
}
```

But, everytime I run my program, every letter that I input a letter, the result is "Oops! Letter is higher".

Help me please. How to run this program properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do `x` and `c` come from? From the code you've posted (the second block) `c` is uninitialised.

Comment: Take a look at the ASCII values for lowercase letters.

Comment: Yes, try to print x and c with System.out.println. Check whether the values are within the range you expect

Comment: As a starting point, I would add the values of x and c to the output to simplify debugging.

Comment: Does `x` contain an upper-case letter? Note that `'Z' < 'a'`

Comment: print x and c for debugging to see if  you are getting correct answer

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`Character.compare(char x, char y)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#compare%28char,%20char%29) to compare characters. It returns an `int` value for showing the difference. However, big question, What is variable `x`? Is it an `int`, another `char` or something completely different. Now, if `x` was a `char` variable, then you could use the following to compare:

So for example:

```
 if (Character.compare(x, c) == 0) {
     // they are the same.
 } else if (Character.compare(x, c) >= 0) {
     // x is greater than c
 } else {
     // x is less than c
 }
```

Comment: It should work as he wrote it as well, ASCII values will be compared.

Comment: x is declared as

>    char x;

Comment: I still always get the result "Oops! Letter is higher"

Comment: What value is x and what value if c?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `char1.compareTo(char2)` method. It will give you the values you're looking for.

More info [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/character_compareto.htm) if you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Random r = new Random();

        char c = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a');

        if ((int)x ==(int)c) {
            prompt.setText("Correct!");
            prompt.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        } else if ((int)x >(int)c) {
            prompt.setText("Oops! Letter is lower");
            prompt.setForeground(Color.RED);
        } else if ((int)x <(int)c) {
            prompt.setText("Oops! Letter is higher");
            prompt.setForeground(Color.RED);
        }
```

Comment: I still always get the result "Oops! Letter is higher"

Comment: Try to compare the Ascii values like: `if ((int)x ==(int)c) {}`

Comment: Cast and store the value in separate int variable then compare. like : `int a= (int) x;` and `int b= (int)c;` then check `if(a==b){}` hope it works,

Comment: Or you can use this to get the Ascii value `int result = CharUtils.CharToASCII(character);`